# Python Bokeh: How to set focus back to TextInput after layout change?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a Bokeh app in which I change the layout during runtime. This app contains a TextInput object which should always be focused, but this focus is lost when I change the layout. Is there a way to automatically set the focus back periodically or after each layout change?

I only found [this related discussion](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/setting-focus-back-to-widget-after-python-on-change-callback/1805), but was unable to apply it to my particular case.

Here is a minimal example where the focus is lost each time you type in the TextInput, triggering a layout change:

```
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from bokeh.models import TextInput
from bokeh.models.widgets import Div
from bokeh.layouts import column


def text_input_change(attr, old, new):
    layout.children[1] = column(text, text_input)


doc = curdoc()
text = Div(text='Test', width=100)
text_input = TextInput(value='', title='', width=100)
text_input.on_change('value_input', text_input_change)
layout = column(text, text_input)
doc.add_root(layout)
```

Comment: There is nothing built-in to Bokeh to control this, so the only viable approach is to call `focus` yourself from a `CustomJS` as in your link. I would suggest you post the code from what attempts you have tried in that direction.

Comment: Have you found a solution since then ? I'm currently facing the same issue. Similar problem can be resolved using ID however does not have one, don't know why.